# proper way to store scraped HTML for re-parsing?

Tags: python, json, postgresql

I'm scraping lots of pages and storing the source in a Postgres database, then determining bits of information to parse and either parsing it with Postgres' own regex, which is super fast, or with Python and BeautifulSoup, row by row, which is perhaps more "proper" but much, much slower.

I'm wondering if I should convert the source to JSON and store in a JSONB field. Seems faster because all the JSON can be indexed...am I wrong? Or maybe switch to MongoDB? I just feel that there must be a faster way. Let's assume, for purposes of argument, that I cannot determine in advance all data that needs to be parsed. Suggestions?

Comment: I'd just store it as a string.

Comment: Well... that's what I'm doing and it seems really slow.

Comment: I guess I still need to do an analysis of exactly which part is the slow part. I'm assuming it is the reading/writing to the database because bs4 seems quite fast by itself. But the Postgres regex parsing is LIGHTSPEED--I can update thousands of rows in a couple seconds. I want to be able to do that with bs4 parsing. And thank you for your response, @RobertMoskal

Comment: I think encoding html markup as json is going to give you something very  difficult to work with.  In fact, I'm not even sure what that would look like.  If you have a general idea of the data you are extracting and want to convert that to json, then sure go ahead.

Comment: @RobertMoskal, should I change my question to, "How can I update rows of a database with bs4 parsing as fast as I can with Postgres regex parsing?" :-)

Comment: Yeah. This is seems too broad a question and isn't likely to get you useful info. If postgres supported xml indexing that might actually speed things up for you.

Comment: But it does support JSON indexing.

Comment: Yup, but i don't see how manipulating that json is going to be pretty